# Set hours minutes and seconds to 00 in ZonedDateTime or Instant

Tags: java, date, java-8, zoneddatetime

I have a date string in Utc format -

```
    String dateStr = "2017-03-03T13:14:28.666Z";
```

And I want to convert it to below format in Java date representation in **ZonedDateTime**.

When **ZonedDateTime** is printed it should show

```
    String dateStr = "2017-03-03T00:00:00.000Z";
```

I have tried following code -

```
    String timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    ZoneId zoneId1 = ZoneId.of(timeZone);
    String dateStr = "2017-03-03T13:14:28.666Z";
    Instant inst = Instant.parse(dateStr, dtf2);


    ZonedDateTime dateTimeInTz = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(inst, zoneId1);

    ZonedDateTime startTime = dateTimeInTz.with(LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0, 0));
    ZonedDateTime endTime = dateTimeInTz.with(LocalTime.MAX);

    System.out.println("Start:"+startTime+", End:"+endTime);
    System.out.println("Start:"+startTime.toString()+", End:"+endTime.toString());  

    ZonedDateTime nT = ZonedDateTime.of ( LocalDate.parse(dateStr, dtf1) , LocalTime.of (0,0,0,0) , ZoneId.of ( timeZone ) );

    System.out.println("Start:"+nT);
```

**Output:**

```
Start:2017-03-03T00:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles], End:2017-03-03T23:59:59.999999999-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
Start:2017-03-03T00:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles], End:2017-03-03T23:59:59.999999999-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
Start:2017-03-03T00:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

I want the start time to be normalized in ZonedDateTime.
I want to achieve it using java libraries only not any third party library.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## tl;dr

You are working too hard.

```
Instant.parse( "2017-03-03T13:14:28.666Z" )
       .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.DAYS )
       .toString()
```

> 2017-03-03T00:00.00Z

## Details

What does "normalized in ZonedDateTime" mean? Please edit your Question to clarify.

> When ZonedDateTime is printed it should show … "2017-03-03T00:00:00.000Z"

What you are asking is a contradiction. A `ZonedDateTime` has an assigned time zone for when you want to view a moment though the wall-clock time of a particular region. So asking for a `ZonedDateTime` to generate a string in UTC such as `"2017-03-03T00:00:00.000Z"` makes no sense. The `Z` is short for `Zulu` and means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Your input string is in standard ISO 8601 format. The java.time classes use these standard formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern, no need for the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

Parse as an `Instant`, a point on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2017-03-03T13:14:28.666Z" );
```

If you want midnight in UTC, truncate.

```
Instant instantMidnightUtc = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.DAYS );
```

> instantMidnightUtc.toString(): 2017-03-03T00:00.00Z

No need for the `ZonedDateTime` class.

If you want to work with a date-only without any time-of-day and without a time zone, use the `LocalDate` class.

By the way, do not assume the first moment of the day is always `00:00:00`. That is true for UTC. But various time zones may have anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) where the day may start at another time-of-day such as `01:00:00`.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
- See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
   String timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    ZoneId zoneId1 = ZoneId.of(timeZone);
    String dateStr = "2017-03-03T13:14:28.666Z";
    Instant inst = Instant.parse(dateStr, dtf2);


    ZonedDateTime dateTimeInTz = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(inst, zoneId1);

    ZonedDateTime startTime = dateTimeInTz.with(LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0, 0));
    ZonedDateTime endTime = dateTimeInTz.with(LocalTime.MAX);

    String strStart = (startTime.toString().split("T"))[0] + "T00:00:00.000Z";
    String strEnd  =  (endTime.toString().split("T"))[0] + "T00:00:00.000Z";

    System.out.println("Start:"+strStart +", End:"+strEnd  );
```

EDIT  new method :

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Copenhagen");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
Calendar defaut = new GregorianCalendar( cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),0,0,0);
```

You juste need to get all your necessary fields. With, for example, a dateFormat.

Hope it will help you

Comment: Yes definitely this is one of the way but is it possible to do using java apis instead of String manipulation.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, can you explain it to me otherwise?

Comment: Like the ones which I had tried but did not worked in the question. e.g setting hours, minutes,seconds to 00 using java

Answer (score -3):

You can simply do:

```
DateUtils.truncate(yourDate, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: with org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils

Comment: Incorrect. Apache DateUtils is for the troublesome old legacy date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. This Question is about their replacement, the java.time classes.

Comment: can you send me the source of this?

Comment: Do you mean about DateUtils for the troublesome legacy classes? The JavaDoc for the Apache Commons Lang project’s [`DateUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) class takes only `Date` & `Calendar` arguments, the legacy classes. If you meant info about the java.time classes, see the [JavaDoc in Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html), and [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Comment: Im talking about java 7 ; yes the DateUtils class takes only Date & calender arguments but he can parse the String to get Date and use truncate  to truncate a date .
Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: As for Java 7, most of the *java.time* functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42584295/642706) for links. No need to ever touch the wretched old classes `Date` & `Calendar` again.